# Audio feedback loop on login screen

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lightdm, systemd, microphone

I use Lightdm and Cinnamon on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Every time the computer boots to the login screen, its microphone input is audible on its loudspeakers, so any noise I make (such as typing my password) is echoed on my loudspeaker. It also becomes louder and louder as the microphone picks up the loudspeaker's echo, which is very annoying. Once I'm past the login screen, the microphone input no longer goes to the loudspeaker and the feedback loop stops.

How could I fix the login screen to not send the microphone input to the loudspeakers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

Initially I suspected the `alsactl restore` functionality to be responsible for the problem and tried resetting the stored settings or disabling the automatic execution of this functionality on boot but that did not help.

Switching to a VT, I logged in circumventing lightdm and took a look at what related processes are running by issuing `sudo ps -Heo user,cmd | grep lightdm`. In the output I noticed `pulseaudio` running as the `lightdm` user which I found unnecessary and suspicious. I disabled it by issuing `machinectl shell lightdm@ /bin/bash` to get a shell as the `lightdm` user then executing `systemctl --user mask pulseaudio` from whithin that shell. Finally I quit that shell (Ctrl-D or `exit`).

As a result, `pulseaudio` is no longer started for the `lightdm` user and it doesn't cause an audio feedback loop on the login screen any more.